# Web user control calling event on another User control

Tags: c#

can this be done?

I have c# .aspx page with two web user controls on both displaying Listview of data.

Now if you delete item from 2nd user control listview I want 1st update to show changes as well.

I've added the following in 2nd user control

```
<%@ Reference VirtualPath="controlOne.ascx" %>
```

And I can call   public void BindListview(); to rebind the listview.

But Listview on controlOne comes back with Null error as can't find listview.

Is there a way around this?

Comment: it's very difficult to determine what you are doing or trying to do if you don't provide a code snippet of both controls that are relevant to the question at hand..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call LoadControl method before working with Public members of the controlOne.ascx

take a look at the sample:[@Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w70c655a%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)